# Creating several files in a specific directory using a for loop and command substitution

Tags: bash

I have just created a new directory called "years" with several subdirectories inside, each of them with the name of a year (i.e., "1980", "1981"...). Now, I want to create 12 files in each of those subdirectories (one file per month).

I need to use a for loop in order to do this, containing command substitution as well. The code I'm trying can be seen below, though my problem is that I don't know how to use command substitution here nor how to create those files in the appropriate subdirectory (when I run this code, they are created in my home directory instead).

```
for $years in 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985; do
           mkdir -p "$years"

                 case $years in 1980)
                                for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
                                touch $i.txt
                                done
                                ;;
                  esac
 done
```

My actual code is longer than this, with a case per year and with 12 files instead of 6.

How could I do that?

NOTE: case statements need to be used for this task (I'm following instructions from a course activity)

Comment: I had to delete my answer because you didn't report your real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `seq` command to get a sequence of numbers, and then use command substitution to use it as the values to iterate over:

```
for i in $(seq 1 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code this way to create the files inside the respective folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
for years in 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985; do
           mkdir -p "$years"

                 case $years in 1980)
                                for i in {1..12}; do
                                touch "$years/$i.txt"
                                done
                                ;;
                  esac
done
```

so you just add the directory inside the touch command, or else you could do a *cd "$years"* before the second for loop and a *cd ..* after the done.

Comment: Does this script include command substitution? I'm following some instructions and my script needs to have at least one $() per case, @Olli

Comment: @aprendiz What is the command whose output you need to substitute?

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure... the instructions only mention that I need to use command substitution in the for loops that create the files